# ASP .Net MVC Model - ViewModel - View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, entity-framework-core, html-helper

I have a problem with using properties from models in my views.
My models:

1. Employee.cs

```
namespace App.Data.Models
{
   
    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Project
    {
        public ProjectType ProjectType { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. ProjectType.cs

```
namespace App.Data.Models
{ 
    public enum ProjectType
    {
       Project1,
       Project2,
       Project3,
       Project4,
    }
}
```

3. EmployeeViewModel.cs

```
namespace App.Data.Models
{
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public List<Project> Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My views:
4. Create.cshtml - in create view I can't validate @Html.ValidationMessageFor - when I comment out 3rd group which is for Projects - message displays. But if the group stays I have an error.

```
@model App.Data.Models.EmployeeViewModel
@using App.Data.Models;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Project, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

        <div class="col-md-10">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Project.Count; i++)
            {<div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Project[i].isSelected)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Project[i].ProjectType)
                </div>
            }
           
</div>           
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

5. Details.cshtml - in this view I don't know how to get to properties - @Model.Employee.LastName - doesn't work

```
@model App.Data.Models.EmployeeViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>@Model.Employee.FirstName @Model.Employee.LastName</h2>

<div>
    <h4>Employee</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project)// Here I don't know how to get to the projects which were checked in create view
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Project)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Employee.Id }) |//This line also doesn't work
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

Comment: What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I am using MVC 5

Comment: And it is your student project or you are trying to earn some money?

Comment: Student project

Comment: Why I was asking because I don' t like to use enum ProjectType. It's better to create a special table. But if you can't change we can continue with enum.

Comment: I can change it if there is a better way. Ultimately I want ot create very flexible app where I can add new employee with FirstName, LastName and Projects to which he is assigned to. And when I am displaying details for this new employee I want to see few extra informations which will display depending on choosen projects. I also want to be able to add new projects - ProjectName with ProjectDescription. That's at least my plan.

Comment: A good plan. Look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we could start with replacing your enum and your Project by another Project db table. Create a new class:

```
public class Project
{ 
[Key]
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public string Description{get; set;}
}
```

And you will need ProjectViewModel class too. It will be used to create a list of your checkboxes.

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{ 
public int ProjectId {get; set;}
public string ProjectName {get; set;}
public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

Your EmployeeViewModel class will be like this:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        public Employee Employee { get; set; }
        public ProjectViewModel[] ProjectViewModels { get; set; }
    }

var  employeeViewModel= new EmployeeViewModel {
Employee=new Employee(),
ProjectViewModels=dbContext.Projects.Select (p=>  
          new ProjectViewModel{Id=p.Id, Name=p.Name} ).ToArray();
}
```

And  your Employee  class is like this:

```
   public class Employee
    {
       [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects {get; set;}
    }
```

And since employee has several projects you need the third table:

```
 public class EmployeeProject
    {
    [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey]
   public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
 [ForeignKey]
   public int ProjectId { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: Okey, so when I am creating for example Deatails view for the employee, I will be using two models - Employee and Project. So should I use EmployeeProject? If so, how to get to FirstName or LastName in this view?

Comment: You don't need to add an EmployeeProject to your ViewModel. Use the viewmodel that extist already.  In you action class you will have to select all projects from Projects table and assign it to Projects list of EmployeeViewModel. Inside of your details  view you replace with this  your enum list.

Comment: Your  EmploeeViewModel keeps a list of  all projects, but your Employee class in only list of selected for this employee projects. Try to fix you Details now.

Comment: So how then I can make that loop for checkboxes for Create view? Don't I need also isSelected property?

Comment: Yes,  you will have to convert  Project to ProjectViewModel. See my answer.

Comment: Could you guide me how to implemet checkbox in Create View and how to display checked projects in Details view? Now that I have so many classes I feel pretty lost. My model in Create action method would be var model = new EmployeeViewModel, right? And then I would have new Employee and new Array of Projects?

Comment: Not array of projects, but array of  ProjectViewModel. See my answer. ProjectViewModel has IsSelect property. It is false by default.

Comment: I have updated my post with my InMemoryDb classes, could you check?

Comment: I like it. But you have to add 2 more data sets. I usually create Db at first using SQL server management studio and fill it with data. After this I am using "EF Core Power Tools" to create EF code-first context. After this I usually can change context manually if I need some small changes. But If have  some large db changes, it is usually faster to change db and after this create a new context using that tools. You can google the tools and install it at your visual studio.

Comment: I have planned to use EF, should have done it earlier. Anyway, your answers really helped me! Thank you. If you had time could you check my new post? I am still struggling with checkbox.

Comment: I edited you question. Now I am preparing my answer about checkboxes. Will post later.